# What fuse in the 2001 Holden Barina XC controls the reverse lights?

Tags: fuse, holden, barina, reverse-lights

This is in regards to a 2001 Holden Barina XC, automatic, 5 door hatch, although it may apply to other similar models.

In the owners manual on the page listing the fuses and their location (chapter 6/26), Reverse lights is nowhere on the list.

Which of the fuses on the list controls the reverse lights?

Answer (score 2):

The reverse lights are linked to the cigarette lighter fuse, which is what it is labelled as in the manual. It is a 10A fuse and can be found in position 26.

Comment: Is this to build rep?

Comment: @SolarMike - It doesn't matter. It is ***completely*** within scope to answer your own questions. Any concerns about it can be [**found here**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Personally I find it more interesting to answer other people's questions - to give back where I can for the few questions (actually less than 5) that I have asked and for the very helpful responses I have received. And I while I could write, submit and answer many many questions I don't have the time.

Comment: "Is this to build rep"? - It's because I spent 45 minutes fiddling around with the fuses and the owners manual figuring out which fuse would fix the reverse lights, and I assumed that anyone else with a similar problem might one day find this information time saving and useful. If I get extra rep on here, I'll take that as evidence that my assumption was not misguided.

Comment: Thank you your plan helped me. I'm going to try it on my kia.